# How can I call a function in ASP.NET from JS to C# in a custom list selector? .NET 4.6

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a custom list selector that handles selecting an item on the front end by setting the value for a hidden field and I access that value on the backend. The problem is I want to raise an event when the value changes but I cannot figure out how to get the function on the backend to be called.

This is the JS logic when a new selection is made:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#modal_<%# this.ClientID %>').hide();
    });

    function onSelected_<%# this.ClientID %>(value, display) {
        var hidSelected = $('#<%# this.hidSelected.ClientID %>');
        $(hidSelected).val(value);
        
        $('#<%# this.txtDisplay.ClientID %>').val(display);
        $('#modal_<%# this.ClientID %>').modal('hide');

        $(hidSelected).trigger('change');
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidSelected" runat="server" />
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't get triggered:

```
<asp:HiddenField OnValueChanged="onNewItemSelected" ID="hidSelected" runat="server" />
```

```
protected void onNewItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.onItemChanged != null)
                this.onItemChanged();
        }
```

I have also tried WebMethod and ajax but I use this as a tag in another page so that doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You appear to be using ASP.Net webforms, so I would suggest using a postback for this, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger a code stub on that page (code behind).

Then just drop in a button (say below the hidden field) like this:

```
        <asp:HiddenField  ID="hidSelected" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdHfield" runat="server" Text="Hfield change"
            OnClick="cmdHfield_Click"
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            style="display:none"
            />
```

And then, your js client side code can be this:

```
            function onSelected_<%# this.ClientID %>(value, display) {
                var hidSelected = $('#<%# this.hidSelected.ClientID %>');
                $(hidSelected).val(value);
    
                $('#<%# this.txtDisplay.ClientID %>').val(display);
                $('#modal_<%# this.ClientID %>').modal('hide');

                $('#cmdHfield').click();

            }
```

so, after the client side code changes the hidden field, then we simple click that button that we dropped right below the hidden field.

Note how we have "hide" the button with style="display:none"

So, there are no "events" that you can attach to a hidden field. However, you are free to drop in a button onto the page, and "click" that button with js code, and that amounts to running code behind on demand from js code anyway.